# Can content from others be monetised?

Tags: copyright

A book author, who normally writes his or her content through many experimentations. Can I produce a content (video/webinar or others) based on the book and claim money for that content ? What does law normally say about it?

Comment: The law in which country or jurisdiction?

Comment: Maybe. Whether this would constitute fair dealing or a derivate work depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: @JohnFx, anywhere in the world, like an Author in Europe wrote a book, and someone from a different region is creating paid online courses based on book's lesson.

Comment: @habibalsaki That's not how laws work. There is no global copyright law that applies everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I produce a content ... based on the book and claim money for that content ?

That depends on what exactly is meant by "based on" You could create your own content discussing the book, or the ideas in the book. That would not infringe the copyright on the source book in any country that I know of. That is, copyright would not make this unlawful or requiem the source author's permission. You could post such content anywhere what will let you, and "monetize" it -- that is, allow ads placed alongside it for which you get money. Doing all that would be legal in any country.

However, if you convert the book, or part of it, to some mother format such as a video or webinar, using the words of the book author for much of the content, that would probably be an infringement of copyright. Such a new work "based on " a per-existing work is called a ***derivative work*** To make a derivative work requires the permission of the copyright owner (often the author) of the original work. If one does not get permission, simply making the derivative work is copyright infringement. Posting it (or distributing it in another way) would be a further infringement. That is true in every country that I know of.

Profiting by such distribution (such as by monetizing it) will increase the seriousness of that infringement, and quite likely increase the damages that the owner could get in a suit. In addition, YouTube and similar platforms have rules against  monetization in such cases, and could take action based on a complaint from the copyright owner even without a lawsuit being filed.

The only way that such a thing might be permissable is if it fit an ***exception to copyright***.  These are different in different countries. In the US the key exception is ***fair use***. In the UK and  several other Commonwealth Countries, it is ***fair dealing***. In other countries different exceptions apply.

Basing a video or the like on a book, while using extensive passages from the book is not likely to be fair use under US law, although the details will matter. It is also not likely to fit under fair dealing, although again details will matter. I am not aware of any exception in any country that would cover the situation described in the question, but I do not know the copyright laws of all countries. Also, note that the owner could potentially sue in any country where the derivative work was distributed, in which case that country's law would apply.

I repeat, creating a video or other work which presents the ideas from the book, giving proper credit, **without** using the words of the book, or closely paraphrasing the book (that is mere superficial sentence by sentence rewriting) will not cause a copyright problem, and could be monetized. Otherwise this probably cannot be done lawfully.

By the way, that the book is created "through many experimentations" will not matter. Each version of the book is protected by copyright. It does not matter if the author wrote the book all at once or through many revisions.

Comment: tl;dr in the fact pattern that the question asked seems to be suggesting, the short answer is "no" he can't do that.

Comment: Your sentence “That would not be protected by copyright …” is confusing as it implies the criticism or commentary would not be protected when it clearly would. I think you mean it would not infringe the original copyright.

Comment: @Dale on review I agree that what I wrote was unclear, so I revised it.

Comment: @ohwilleke
 True, But I didn't think it was at all clear what the OP actually intended to do, or wanted an answer about.

Comment: @DavidSiegel , thanks a lot for your answer. I know my question is a bit generic, but truly, the whole context is a bit generic too. So it is difficult to ask specific question sometimes. Like blinkist is issuing summary of book, people are creating udemy course on self help book lessons, they arrange webinar on how to learn based on Barbara Oakley's book with some fees. Many examples can be given from different perspectives.